# How can I solve the ACE value problem with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, api, blackjack

So Ace should have value 11 or value 1 depending on the other cards. Let's say our starting cards are ACE and SIX. That's 7 or 17. If we hit for another card and it's FOUR,
we have Blackjack and the value of ACE should be 11.
And other scenarios like this

I'm converting the ACE value from the API in the convertToNum function.

Here is the whole code: https://jsfiddle.net/unote2zf/

Here is my JS code:

```
//DOM
let deckId = ""; //we store our deck in global variable
let playerCardOne,
  playerCardTwo,
  dealerClosedCard,
  dealerCardTwo,
  sumPlayersCards,
  sumDealersCards;

//first card for the dealer
let dealerCardOne = document.querySelector(".dealer-card1");

let result = document.querySelector(".result");

const dealerCards = document.querySelector(".dealer-cards");
const playerCards = document.querySelector(".player-cards");

const dealerScore = document.querySelector(".dealer-score");
const playerScore = document.querySelector(".player-score");

//Buttons
const dealButton = document.querySelector(".deal");
const hitButton = document.querySelector(".hit");
const standButton = document.querySelector(".stand");

//we store value from the cards here
let addPlayersCards = [];
let addDealersCards = [];

//Event listeners
dealButton.addEventListener("click", dealCards);
hitButton.addEventListener("click", hit);
standButton.addEventListener("click", stand);

async function getDeck() {
  try {
    let res = await fetch("https://www.deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/new/shuffle/?deck_count=2");
    let data = await res.json()
    console.log(data);
    deckId = data.deck_id;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
};
getDeck();

async function dealCards() {

  addDealersCards.push(await getCard());
  addPlayersCards.push(await getCard());
  addDealersCards.push(await getCard());
  addPlayersCards.push(await getCard());

  // dealerScore.textContent = convertToNum(addDealersCards[1].cards[0].value);

  dealButton.classList.toggle("hide");
  hitButton.classList.toggle("hide");
  standButton.classList.toggle("hide");
  dealerScore.classList.toggle("hide");
  playerScore.classList.toggle("hide");

  console.log(addPlayersCards)

  console.log(addDealersCards)

  renderCards();
  sumCards();
  if (sumPlayersCards === 21) {
    result.innerText = "BLACKJACK PLAYER WINS";
    flipDealersFirstCard();
    checkForWinner();
  }
}

async function hit() {
  addPlayersCards.push(await getCard());
  sumCards();
  renderPlayersCard();

  //If player goes over 21 to finish the game and open the dealers cards
  if (sumPlayersCards >= 21) {
    flipDealersFirstCard();
    checkForWinner(); 
  }
}


async function stand() {
  flipDealersFirstCard();

  //To hit the Dealer till he's over 17 or over
  while (sumDealersCards < 17) {
    addDealersCards.push(await getCard());
    sumCards();
    renderDealersCard();
  }

  // sumCards()
  checkForWinner();
}

//Deal one card
async function getCard() {
  try {
    let res = await fetch(`https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/${deckId}/draw/?count=1`);
    let data = await res.json()
    console.log(data)
    return data.cards[0];

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
};

function sumCards() {
  sumPlayersCards = 0;
  addPlayersCards.forEach(element => {
  sumPlayersCards += convertToNum(element.value);
  console.log(element.value)
});
  sumDealersCards = 0;
  addDealersCards.forEach(element => {
    sumDealersCards += convertToNum(element.value);
    console.log(element.value)
  })
  dealerScore.textContent = convertToNum(addDealersCards[addDealersCards.length - 1].value);
  playerScore.textContent = sumPlayersCards;

  console.log(sumDealersCards)
  console.log(sumPlayersCards)

}

//Draw the cards in the arrays
function renderCards() {
  addDealersCards.forEach(element => {
    let cardElement = document.createElement("img");
    dealerCards.appendChild(cardElement);
    cardElement.src = element.image;
    dealerCards.firstElementChild.src = "https://opengameart.org/sites/default/files/card%20back%20red.png";
  })

  addPlayersCards.forEach(element => {
    let cardElement = document.createElement("img");
    playerCards.appendChild(cardElement);
    cardElement.src = element.image;
  })
}

function renderPlayersCard() {
  let cardElement = document.createElement("img");
  playerCards.appendChild(cardElement);
  cardElement.src = addPlayersCards[addPlayersCards.length - 1].image;
  // playerScore.textContent = sumCards();
}


function renderDealersCard() {
  let cardElement = document.createElement("img");
  dealerCards.appendChild(cardElement);
  cardElement.src = addDealersCards[addDealersCards.length - 1].image;
  dealerScore.textContent = sumDealersCards;
}

//To flip the first card for the dealer and sum dealers cards.
function flipDealersFirstCard() {
  dealerCards.firstElementChild.src = addDealersCards[0].image;
  dealerScore.textContent = sumDealersCards;
  console.log(sumDealersCards);
}

//To convert the cards with string Values
function convertToNum(val) {
  if (val === "ACE") {
    return 11;
  } 
  else if (val === "KING" || val === "QUEEN" || val === "JACK") {
    return 10;
  } 
  else {
    return Number(val);
  }
}

//Checks who won
function checkForWinner() {
  if (sumPlayersCards > sumDealersCards && sumPlayersCards < 21) {
    result.classList.toggle("hide");
    result.innerText = "PLAYER WINS";
  } else if (sumDealersCards > 21 && sumPlayersCards <= 20) {
    result.classList.toggle("hide");
    result.innerText = "PLAYER WINS";
  } else if (sumPlayersCards === 21 && sumDealersCards <= 20) {
    result.classList.toggle("hide");
    result.innerText = "BLACKJACK PLAYER WINS";
  } else if (sumDealersCards > sumPlayersCards && sumDealersCards < 21) {
    result.classList.toggle("hide");
    result.innerText = "DEALER WINS";
  } else if (sumPlayersCards > 21 && sumDealersCards <= 20) {
    result.classList.toggle("hide");
    result.innerText = "BUST! DEALER WINS";
  } else if (
    (sumDealersCards === 21 && sumPlayersCards <= 20) ||
    sumPlayersCards > 21
  ) {
    result.classList.toggle("hide");
    result.innerText = "BLACKJACK DEALER WINS";
  } else {
    result.classList.toggle("hide");
    result.innerText = "DRAW";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In sumCards() count ACE as 11 by default.

If the total is > 21 :

- count the number of ACEs
- in a loop till this number or till the total is < 22, remove 10 from the total